# How do we use AWSSDK.Core in a project which is multi-targeting .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET FX 4.7.2

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, .net-standard, aws-sdk-net, .net-standard-2.1

I am in the process of upgrading a business layer project(netfx472) and due to some constraints I have to make it multi-target .NET Standard 2.1 and .NET FX 4.7.2 after the upgrade.

It's currently using AWSSDK.Core and I don't see a version of that package supporting .NET Standard 2.1. What are my options in moving ahead with this upgrade. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Looks like it targets older runtimes with which your targets should be compatible. https://www.nuget.org/packages/awssdk.core/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: Thanks! it all makes sense now, wish the .NET standard package support was more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is evident to me on now how .NET Standard support works between 2.0 and 2.1 - assemblies/packages targeting STD 2.0 are also compatible with STD 2.1. Leaving this answer here to help others with the same query.